# Ember observer when session is active on page load

Tags: ember.js

I am writing a EmberJS web application. I have a piece of code which should run *only* when the page has completed loaded and the session authentication is complete.

I tried setting an observer on session.isAuthenticated but it does not seem to be working.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didTransition` hook of the particular route. You need to define it in actions hash, and dont forget to return true for bubbling to the parent route.
Inside didTransition hook, if you want to run some thing after the page has been rendered, then you can try,

```
Ember.run.schedule("afterRender",() => {
//you code
});
```